# how to set initial value from my model choice field

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

hello guys i've got two models one for members and one for entries the relationship is foreign key since one member can have many entries.
i've managed to make make a page for viewing each member and their entries. i want to add a form that will add another entry to a that particular user and redirected to the page of that member id once the saveing process is completed also,, i want to display the name id of that member to a name field as initial value once the form is displayed, i i have used modelchoice field to display all of the members available